# How to terminate an ssh session that calls python's multiprocessing

Tags: python, bash, ssh, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've got a program that runs on a server that is accessed by clients. Clients can issue commands to the server via ssh like so:

```
ssh user@server activate
```

This command executes a bash script which in turn executes a Python 2.7 script. The python script then spawns up a child process using python's `Multiprocessing.Process()` class. This child process is intended to persist and run tasks in the background (e.g. for > 1 month) until it is told to stop by another ssh command.

An example of the python script (`test.py`) that runs some arbitrary open-ended function on a separate process:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process


def run_child_process(callback_func):
    child = Process(target=callback_func)
    child.start()


def task():
    while True:
        # Do some arbitrary task continually.
        print("Running")
        sleep(300)


def run():
    run_child_process(task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

This script is called via a bash script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m test.py > /dev/null
```

My problem is that the ssh session does not close after the child process is created. While the original parent process completes, it seems the presence of the newly created child process is preventing the ssh session from being closed.

If I run the child process using `os.fork()` instead, the ssh call exits correctly and leaves the child process running:

```
def create_child_fork(callback_func):
    if os.fork() > 0:
        return
    os.setsid()
    callback_func()
    sys.exit()
```

I'm wondering why the same does not seem to be possible using `multiprocessing.Process()`.